# Google Maps URL Not Found

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have been using a Google Maps URL in order to get a route from two different sets of GPS coordinates.

URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=34.019283,-118.494286&daddr=34.021564,-118.490112
```

[[Link]](http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=34.019283,-118.494286&daddr=34.021564,-118.490112)

We have been using this URL for months and this morning this URL is returning a 404 error. Is this URL the wrong way to retrieve a route from Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

That URL is the "classic" google maps. It might have been turned off. You will need to replace it using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/) (or one of the other Google Maps APIs).